# WiseJ Implementation of FullCalendar IO

Tags: fullcalendar, schedule, wisej

**WiseJ** implements an extension of Fullcalendar but the enum listing of its ViewTypes does not appear to include the free feature/view named **"TimeGrid"**.

In contrast the premium **"Timeline"** is in the enum list and invokable when I reference their Non production trial License/SchedulerLicenseKey.
(*the calendar's view dynamically updates accordingly*)

There is no Javascript interface to perform magic and call up a specific plugin of this control when using this in the WiseJ Extension.
(*None that I am aware of*)

**How do I apply the free feature view, one of the "TimeGrid" styles, day week, etc, if its not available in the enum list of ViewTypes?**  I've spewed the enums to a combo box and, again,  I can dynamically change them but again with the premium view requiring the Non production trial License/SchedulerLicenseKey.

I don't even need to change the view dynamically, I just need to access the non premium view named "TimeGrid" to use it for scheduling.